# Compare 2 List to get the unequal ones

Tags: windows, powershell

I have 2 lists (client,node) and I only need the clients where the nodename is unequal the servername.

Every list is in an own file one is called client.txt and the other one is called node.txt

Here is an example:

```
Client:   Server:
one.local one.local
two.local two.local
3.local   4.local
4.local   5.local
```

and now I want to get only the 3.local because he is the onlyone without the same server.

Thanks for your help
VallingSki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$client = get-content .\client.txt
$server = get-content .\server.txt
Foreach ($Line in $Client) {
    If ($Server -notcontains $line ) {
        $Line
    }
}
```

Result:

> 3.local

Or even simpeler

```
$client = get-content .\client.txt
$server = get-content .\server.txt
$Client | Where-Object {$server -notcontains $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Contains` method e.g.:

```
$client = @('one.local', 'two.local', '3.local', '4.local')
$server = @('one.local', 'two.local', '4.local', '5.local')

$client | % { if (-not $server.Contains($_)) {$_}}
```

Or even simpler:

```
$client | where { $server -notcontains $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using compare-object, if I understand your question:

```
compare-object (cat client.txt) (cat server.txt) | ? sideindicator -eq '<='

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
3.local     <=
```